# What should be an equivalent [routerLink] code for this.router.navigate code?

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, angular2-routing, routerlink

```
   showBio(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['/speakers', {outlets: {'bio': [id]}}]);
}
```

How can I write it in [routerLink] and still can pass an id?
I am following this example for reference: [Example](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/)

Comment: you need to bind click event and in function you can write navigate line

Comment: Yes, and that is working fine for me. However, I want to use it with [routerLink] as that should also be possible. I was earlier using [routerLink] without named routers. Now I am updating it with named outlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route syntax stays the same with `[routerLink]` :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/speakers', {outlets: {'bio': [id]}}]">Link</a>
```

For this to work, the `id` property needs to be exposed to your template.

Comment: I also tried the same thing. But I am getting this error:
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'speakers'

At the same time, I am able to navigate to particular speaker bio by ShowBio(id).

Comment: Did you use exactly this path - `'speakers'` - including the initial slash? Maybe you need to adjust the path. By default, routerLink paths are relative to the current path. My code assumes you have a `/speakers` **at the root** of your app.

Comment: yes, it is there in root routing module without '/'.

Comment: Strange. And if you try the link without the `outlets` part, does it work?